# Unexpected line break due to `foreigndisplaycquote`-environment using `biblatex` and `polyglossia` with Persian as foreign language

Tags: biblatex, citing, line-breaking, polyglossia, persian

I am using the `foreigndisplaycquote`-environment from the csquotes package for longer quotations in foreign languages in my document. It is set up like this:

```
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\renewcommand{\mkccitation}[1]{#1}
```

Unfortunately, this gives me an empty line after every footnote originating from a `foreigndisplaycquote`-environment. The empty line disappears when I disable Persian as other language. This, unfortunately, is not an option though, as my document contains Persian text that needs to be put in the respective environment provided by `polyglossia`. I am assuming, that this issue is somehow related to `biblatex` not supporting Persian?

What can I do to get rid of the empty line (=easy work around)?

Is there any way that I can actually help `biblatex` supporting Persian?

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{article} % 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{english,persian}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\renewcommand{\mkccitation}[1]{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{fiktiv:quelle,
        author = {Author Lastname},
        title = {Title of the Book},
        year = {2023},
        publisher = {Publisher}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    Text vor dem Zitat.\autocite{fiktiv:quelle}
    
    \begin{foreigndisplaycquote}{english}[][12]{fiktiv:quelle}[.]
        This is a longer quotation in a foreign language from a fictional source
    \end{foreigndisplaycquote}
    
    Text zwischen den Zitaten.
    
    Hier ist ein weiterer Verweis auf die Quelle: \autocite{fiktiv:quelle}.
    
    Text nach den Zitaten.
    
\end{document}
```

[image: line break after footnote 2, should not be there]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some back and forth with the options provided by `biblatex`, lead to nothing, I have found a work-around. I am still assuming that this problem is connected to [`biblatex` not supporting Persian](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1139), as the issue disappears when not using Persian as a `otherlanguage`. Instead of using the `foreigndisplaycquote` environment, I am now using the `displaycquote` environment and changing the language manually. This, for reasons I do not understand, solves the problem of the additional line break.

**Solution:**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{english,persian}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\renewcommand{\mkccitation}[1]{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{fiktiv:quelle,
        author = {Author Lastname},
        title = {Title of the Book},
        year = {2023},
        publisher = {Publisher}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    Text vor dem Zitat.\autocite{fiktiv:quelle}
    
    \begin{displaycquote}[][12]{fiktiv:quelle}[.]
        \textenglish{This is a longer quotation in a foreign language from a fictional source}
    \end{displaycquote}
    
    Text zwischen den Zitaten.
    
    Hier ist ein weiterer Verweis auf die Quelle: \autocite{fiktiv:quelle}.
    
    Text nach den Zitaten.
    
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:
[image: now everything is aligned, as I asked for. No excess line breaks.]

If anyone has an idea why this is happening, I would still appreciate a more thorough answer. For the time being though, I am assuming that it is a bug in the implementation of the `foreigndisplaycquote` environment in `csquotes`. I will try to report the bug, once I have tracked down the correct place to do so.